# want A column value in C column if B column have yes word in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

want A column value in C column if B column have yes word in google sheet ..

for ex:

```
A column        ---  B column     -----   C column
1               ---  yes          -----    1
2               ---               -----       
3               ----               -----          
4               ----  yes          -----   4
```

i try using this formula
`=IF(SEARCH("yes",B1), CONCATENATE(A1, " "), "")`

and it works  but i want to show C column values in other sheet 
like in one sheet i have two sheets .. Sheet1 have these A column  and B column values .. and i want to use this formula in sheet2 to get this result but its not work .. can you please help me in this and one more thing 
can i use it like " =IF(SEARCH("yes",B1:B), CONCATENATE(A1:A, " "), "")"
i mean rang , i dont wont to run this manually every time when i insert new value in a column and in b column . rang define and it will do the rest automatic in sheet2   .. i hope you understand my question .. thanks

Comment: any help ????? please help me

Comment: you question in very confusing.  For example  you state "...like in one sheet I have two sheets."  this is not possible.  It sounds like you are using the sheet to mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

First I will use to compare two strings "Exact" instead of "search".
You can use:
=ArrayFormula(IF(EXACT(B2:B;"yes");B2:B;""))
With array formula your formula will apply to all rows that you will fill.

If you want to use this formula from other sheet, you should add the name of the sheet before, the following formula will work if your table is in a sheet called "Hoja 2"".
=ArrayFormula(IF(EXACT('Hoja 2'!B2:B;"yes");'Hoja 2'!B2:B;""))

Comment: thanks for help but i used other method and my problem was solved .. thanks again for your time.